# mongodb micro-optimization of batch inserts ? or is this an important optimization?

Tags: mongodb, document-oriented-db, database, nosql

**premise** : update statements are harmless since the driver by default works in one way messaging (as long as `getLastError` isn't used).

**question** Is the following fragment the best way to do this in mongodb for high volume inserts ? Is it possible to fold step 2 and 3 ?

**edit : old buggy form , see below**

```
// step 1 : making sure the top-level document is present (an upsert in the real 
            example)
db.test.insert( { x :1} )

// step 2 : making sure the sub-document entry is present
db.test.update( { x:1 }, { "$addToSet" : { "u" : { i : 1, p : 2 } } }, false)

// step 3 : increment a integer within the subdocument document
db.test.update( { x : 1, "u.i" : 1}, { "$inc" : { "u.$.c" : 1 } },false)
```

I have a feeling there is no way out of operation 3, since the`$` operator requires priming in the query field of the query part of an update. amirite ? iamrite ?

If this is the best way to do things, can I get creative in my code and go nuts with update operations ?

**edit : new form**

There was a bug in my logic, thanks Gates. Still want to fold the updates if possible :D

```
// make sure the top-level entry exists and increase the incidence counter
db.test.update( { x : 1 }, { $inc : { i : 1 } }, true ) --1

// implicetly creates the array
db.test.update(   { x : 1 , u : { $not : { $elemMatch : { i : 1 } } } } , 
                  { $push : { u : { i : 1 , p :2 , c:0} } }) -- 2

db.test.update( { x :1 , "u.i" : 1}, { $inc : { "u.$.c" : 1 } },false) --3
```

notes : `$addToSet` is not usefull in this case, since it does a element-wise match, there is no way to express what elements in an array may be `mutable` as in C++ OO bitwise comparison parlance

**question is pointless** Data model is wrong. Please vote to close (OP).

Answer (score 1):

So, the first thing to note is that the `$` positional operator is a little sketchy. It has a lot of "gotchas": it doesn't play well with upserts, it only affects the first true match, etc.

To understand "folding" of #2 and #3, you need to look at the output of your commands:

```
db.test.insert( { x :1} )
{ x:1 } // DB value

db.test.update( { x:1 }, { "$addToSet" : { "u" : { i : 1, p : 2 } } }, false)
{ x:1, u: [ {i:1,p;2} ] } // DB value

db.test.update( { x : 1, "u.i" : 1}, { "$inc" : { "u.$.c" : 1 } },false)
{ x:1, u: [ {i:1,p:2,c:1} ] } // DB value
```

Based on the sequence you provided, the whole thing can be rolled into a single update.

If you're only looking to roll together #2 & #3, then you're worried about matching `'u.i':1` with `u.$.c`. But there are some edge cases here you have to clarify.

Let your starting document be the following:

```
{ 
  x:1, 
 u: [ 
      {i:1, p:2},
      {i:1, p:3}  
    ] 
}
```

What do you expect from running update #3?

As written you get:

```
{ 
  x:1, 
 u: [ 
      {i:1, p:2, c:1},
      {i:1, p:3}  
    ] 
}
```

Is this correct? Is that first document legal? (*semantically correct*)? Depending on the answers, this may actually be an issue of document structure.

Comment: You are right, it is illegal. 'c' should be a mutable element of the set :/.